# Track the reading of emails in a case - notification/escalation

Tags: apex, customization

We would like to track the time it takes for an agent to open an email reply to a case. If an email is unopened for a length of time we need to send out a notification or escalate the case to a manager.

Please reply with any coding or configuration that will help in this regard.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you refer to is Escalation rules

[Creating Escalation Rules](https://eu1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customize_escrules.htm)

Once configured correctly, you can have detailed reports as well times, and processes on cases.

Answer (score 0):

Apex solution is to have an email service which monitors inbound email and creates a task assigned to the case owner with a due date and time as desired.